# JQueryMobile Slider Change Event - Show Images

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider

I have a slider functioning [here](http://dev10.edisbest.com/flash/slide2/).

What i want to do is when slider goes in between 10-20, 21-40, 41-60, 61-80, 81-100 i want image to be replaced with another, you can see a default image which i want to be replaced...

So for example if slider is in between 21-40 image source should be changed to

```
<img src="images/slide_2.jpg" width="459" height="315">
```

and so on.. how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/YgJ9P/2/

JS:

```
$("#slider").change(function() {
    sVal = $(this).val();

    if(sVal > 21 && sVal <= 40) {
        $('#theImage').attr('src', 'http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/21-skull.png');
    }

    if(sVal > 41 && sVal <= 60) {
        $('#theImage').attr('src', 'http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/18-envelope.png');
    }

    if(sVal > 61 && sVal <= 80) {
        $('#theImage').attr('src', 'http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/100-coffee.png');
    }

    if(sVal > 81 && sVal <= 100) {
        $('#theImage').attr('src', 'http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/88-beermug.png');
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="slider-test" data-theme="a"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="slider">Input slider: 
                <img id="theImage" src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/09-chat2.png" alt="slider images" />
            </label>
            <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100"  />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, if you add type attribute to your slider tag like so `type="slider"`, it'll become a html5 slider object and will have a change event where you can check its current value. So your code would like something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slider").change(function () {
            if (slider.value > 20 && slider.value < 41)
                $("#imgMap").attr("src", "images/slide_2.jpg");
        });
    });
```

if you give your image id="imgMap"

```
<img id="imgMap" src="images/slide_1.jpg" width="459" height="315">
<input type="slider" name="slider" id="slider" value="47" min="0" max="100" 
    data-type="range">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as per your suggestion i tried it at http://tinyurl.com/3q4r7gq but its not working.. ?

Comment: you have syntax error in your mark-up. check javascript console